# VBA excel, run macro in cell range that = to "yes"

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("z12:z15")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        If Range("Z12:Z45).value = "yes" then
            MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I have problems figuring this out. any help would be appreciated.
tx

luigi

Comment: You need to check if any cell in the `Target` (changed) range has "yes"?

Comment: That is right. This code right now is giving me error.

Comment: _Target_ is a range ... use `... Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) ...`

Comment: the error seems to come from this ---> If Range("Z12:Z45).value = "yes" then

Comment: this counts how many times "yes" is found in the range ... so use `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("Z12:Z45), "yes") > 0 Then`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VBA, you cannot compare an array (`Range("Z12:Z45").value`) to a constant ("yes") or anything else for that matter. You need either to loop on the cells of the range (or entries of the array), or possibly use the `Match` or `CountIf` functions.

Moreover, to check for changes, you need to examine the `Target` range, not the `Range("z12:z15")`. Here's how to do it with a loop:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range, cel As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("z12:z15")

    If Not Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
       For Each cel In Intersect(KeyCells, Target)
         If StrComp(cel.text, "yes", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
           MsgBox "Cell " & cel.Address & " has changed."
         End If
       Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: works like a charm! Thank-you for sharing your knowledge.